# Writing to $HOME from a jar file

Tags: java, scala, bitcoin

I'm trying to write to a file located in my $HOME directory. The code to write to that file has been packaged into a jar file. When I run the unit tests to package the jar file, everything works as expected - namely the file is populated and can be read from again.

When I try to run this code from another application where the jar file is contained the `lib` directory it fails. The file is created - but the file is never written to. When the app goes to read the file it fails parsing it because it is empty.

Here is the code that writes to the file:

```
  logger.warn("TestNet wallet does not exist creating one now in the directory: " + walletPath)
  testNetFileName.createNewFile()
  logger.warn("Wallet file name: " + testNetFileName.getAbsolutePath)
  logger.warn("Can write: "+ testNetFileName.canWrite())
  logger.warn("Can read: " + testNetFileName.canRead)
  val w = Wallet.fromWatchingKey(TestNet3Params.get(), testNetSeed)
  w.autosaveToFile(testNetFileName, savingInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, null)
  w
}
```

here is the log form the above method that is relevant:

```
2015-12-30 15:11:46,416 - [WARN] - from class com.suredbits.core.wallet.ColdStorageWallet$ in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9 
TestNet wallet exists, reading in the one from disk

2015-12-30 15:11:46,416 - [WARN] - from class com.suredbits.core.wallet.ColdStorageWallet$ in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9 
Wallet file name: /home/chris/testnet-cold-storage.wallet
```

then it bombs.

Here is the definition for `autoSaveToFile`

```
public WalletFiles autosaveToFile(File f, long delayTime, TimeUnit timeUnit,
                                  @Nullable WalletFiles.Listener eventListener) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        checkState(vFileManager == null, "Already auto saving this wallet.");
        WalletFiles manager = new WalletFiles(this, f, delayTime, timeUnit);
        if (eventListener != null)
            manager.setListener(eventListener);
        vFileManager = manager;
        return manager;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

and the definition for `WalletFiles`

https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/WalletFiles.java#L68

```
public WalletFiles(final Wallet wallet, File file, long delay, TimeUnit delayTimeUnit) {
    // An executor that starts up threads when needed and shuts them down later.
    this.executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new ContextPropagatingThreadFactory("Wallet autosave thread", Thread.MIN_PRIORITY));
    this.executor.setKeepAliveTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    this.executor.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
    this.wallet = checkNotNull(wallet);
    // File must only be accessed from the auto-save executor from now on, to avoid simultaneous access.
    this.file = checkNotNull(file);
    this.savePending = new AtomicBoolean();
    this.delay = delay;
    this.delayTimeUnit = checkNotNull(delayTimeUnit);

    this.saver = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() throws Exception {
            // Runs in an auto save thread.
            if (!savePending.getAndSet(false)) {
                // Some other scheduled request already beat us to it.
                return null;
            }
            log.info("Background saving wallet, last seen block is {}/{}", wallet.getLastBlockSeenHeight(), wallet.getLastBlockSeenHash());
            saveNowInternal();
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I'm guessing it is some sort of permissions issue but I cannot seem to figure this out.

EDIT: This is all being run on the exact same Ubuntu 14.04 machine - no added complexity of different operating systems.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: What is `testNetFileName` and what is `autosaveToFile`?

Comment: As @MadProgrammer wrote use `user.home`. `user.home` will always exist. Even if your code is running as root/system user there will be a home directory for that user.

Comment: I actually tried using `user.home` and I was running into issues using it with `sudo`. I was unable to create a file in the directory - which was `root/` if I remember correctly

Comment: Where is `saveNowInternal()`?

Comment: @Dima https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/wallet/WalletFiles.java#L110

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generally depend on the existence or writability of `$HOME`.  There are really only two portable ways to identify (i.e. provide a path to) an external file.

1. Provide an explicit path using a property set on the invocation command line or provided in the environment, or
2. Provide the path in a configuration properties file whose location is itself provided as a property on the command line or in the environment.

The problem with using `$HOME` is that you cannot know what userID the application is running under.  The user may or may not even *have* a home directory, and even if the user does, the directory may or may not be writable.  In your specific case, your process may have the ability to create a file (write access on the directory itself) but write access to a file may be restricted by the umask and/or ACLs (on Windows) or selinux (on Linux).

Put another way, the installer/user of the library must explicitly provide a known writable path for your application to use.

Yet another way to think about it is that you are writing library code that may be used in completely unknown environments.  You cannot assume ANYTHING about the external environment except what is in the explicit contract between you and the user. You can declare in your interface specification that `$HOME` must be writable, but that may be highly inconvenient for some users whose environment doesn't have `$HOME` writable.

A much better and portable solution is to say

> specify `-Dcom.xyz.workdir=[path]` on the command line to indicate the work path to be used

or

> The xyz library will look for its work directory in the path specified by the `XYZ_WORK` environment variable

Ideally, you do BOTH of these to give the user some flexibility.

Comment: I should have stated that this is all being run on Ubuntu 14.04 machines, so there should be some consistency there in the $HOME variable, correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. If you are in a library you cannot assume ANYTHING about the external environment except what is in the explicit contract between you and the user.  You can declare in your interface specification that `$HOME` must be writable, but that may be highly inconvenient for some users.  Much better to say _"specify `-Dcom.mylib.workdir=[path]` to indicate the work path to be used"_ or _"The xyz library will look for its work directory in the path specified by the `XYZ_WORK` environment variable"_

Comment: @ChrisStewart **all** my daemon programs run as their own user. They have **no home directory** and must have the paths they can write to explicitly set. If running in production, this would be further reinforced by AppArmor. As this answer states, never assume that there is any writeable location available to you unless you explicitly ask the user to give you one!

Answer (score 1):

`savePending` is always false. In the beginning of `call` you check that it is `false`, and return `null`. The actual save code is never executed. I am guessing you meant to check if it was `true` there, and also set it to `true`, not `false`. You then also need to reset it back to `false` in the end.

Now, why this works in your unit test is a different story. The test must be executing different code.